# Navegação entre telas no Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Estou fazendo um app onde eu preciso abrir navegar para uma nova tela quando clicar em algum container da GridView, tava funcionando normalmente quando os conteiner estavam cada um  em um  InkWell,  mas o codigo está ficando muito confuso então decidi otimizar, mas agora não estou conseguindo chamar um nova tela no Navigator.
OBS: Por enquanto só fiz 2 teles por isso clamei a mesma tela  em todos os buildGridView.

```
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,

                            child: GridView.count(
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 25,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 25,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),

                              children: <Widget>[
                                buildGridView("Quartos",context, 
                                RoomsScreen()),
                                buildGridView("Sala 
                                Principal",context,RoomsScreen()),
                              buildGridView("Cozinha",context,RoomsScreen()),
                               buildGridView("Garage",context,RoomsScreen()),
                                buildGridView("Área 
                                Externa",context,RoomsScreen()),
                            buildGridView("Adicionar",context,RoomsScreen()),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ])))],
                              ),
                                   ],
                                        ),
                                       );
                                       }
                                      }
                  Widget buildGridView(String text, BuildContext context, 
                 String page,){
                  return InkWell(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                   highlightColor: Colors.red,
                     onTap: () {
                     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
                  (context) => page));
                        },
                   child: Container(
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            border: Border.all(
                                 color: Colors.black,
                                width: 2,
                                     )),
                                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                                   child: Column(
                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                         text,
                                     style: TextStyle(
                                         color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: (15)),
                                                    )
                                                     ])));

                                                         }
```

Comment: Dê preferência por utilizar rotas com Nome ao invés de passar um Widget todas as vezes para o MaterialPage, como você mesmo diz o código "era" na verdade ainda está, lembre-se em Flutter tudo é um Widget, dívida o seu código em pequenos Widgets/Métodos que façam o trabalho de maneira simples e que seja fácil de ler.

Comment: Obrigado fiz isso que vc falou. agora está bem melhor.